# Get a count and average from a couple rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using Microsoft SQL Server, I'm trying to get the average days it took someone to complete a transaction in a given month.

Each user has hundreds of transactions so I'm looking for a way to get the count on how many transactions for each person and then their average for the month. I also need to make sure that I remove any NULL returns and convert any negatives to a Zero but keep it accounted for.

Example would look like (Max | 300 | 12.5) for (Person | Transactions | Average).

I've been able to get as far as:

```
SELECT 
    [Transaction],
    [NAME],
    DATEDIFF (d, [Startdate], [Closedate]) AS Days
FROM 
    [Table]
WHERE 
    YEAR ([Startdate]) = 2021
    AND MONTH ([Closedate]) = 11
    AND Closedate IS NOT NULL
```

I've tried to figure out how to incorporate a CASE statement but it's not working when I tried to do it before the `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: `count()`, `avg()`

Comment: You save nothing by using "d" rather than "day" in your datediff function - stop the laziness. But the first step is to actually compute the completion value for each transaction since you need to average it. I think you make an assumption that is risky. Is it reasonable to assume that StartDate and CloseDate are always in the same month? If not, look closely at your where clause and think about which rows you actually select. Consider what happens when a transaction is started in December and Closed in January.

Comment: You can use a `case` _expression_ for various things, e.g. `Sum( case when SomeColumn < 0 then 0 else SomeColumn end )` to sum the non-negative values for a column or `Sum( case when SomeColumn < 0 then 1 else 0 end )` to count the negative values.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like you can just do a simple `GROUP BY` with conditional aggregation.**

To avoid repeating the `DATEDIFF` calculation you can stuff it into a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`.

Always use date intervals such as `>= AND <` rather than using functions on date columns

```sql
SELECT 
    t.NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.Days > 0 THEN v.Days ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDays
FROM 
    [Table] t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    DATEDIFF(day, t.Startdate, t.Closedate)
)) v(Days)
WHERE 
    t.Startdate >= '20211101'
    AND t.Startdate < '20211201'
    AND t.Closedate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    t.NAME;
```